# Как сделать запуск программы глобально Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Скачал ide phpstorm, запуск делаю переходя в директорию `downloads/phpstorm/bin/phpstorm.sh` командой `./phpstorm.sh`.
Как сделать чтобы можно было запускать phpstorm как глобальную программу просто введя в терминале команду `./phpstorm` и не важно в какой директории я нахожусь ?

Comment: А что мешает сделать ярлык для запуска на рабочем столе/в панели и т.д.?

Comment: глобально запускается все из каталогов, перечисленных в переменной окружение PATH. либо положите ваш скрипт в одну из таких директорий (например /usr/local/bin) или добавьте ваш каталог в PATH (см. /etc/env.d или как то так, в разных системах начальное окружение формируется по разному). В таком случае при запуске надо будет просто писать `phpstorm.sh` без `./` означающей запуск из текущего каталога. И да, что бы запускать командой без .sh раширения у скрипта быть не должно вообще

Comment: @Mike, *например /usr/local/bin* - `~/bin` для этого существует (если, конечно, нет задачи осчастливить вообще всех юзеров этой машины).

Comment: @PinkTux может в ubuntu ~/bin и есть в путях, но в доступных мне системах такого нет.

Comment: @Mike, в убунтоидах добавление `~/bin` (если такой каталог существует) в PATH  прописывается из коробки либо в `~/.profile`, либо в `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/pathToPhpstorm.sh
```

можно будет запускать из любого места `phpstorm.sh`. можно добавить в `.bash_profile` или `.bashrc`.

Comment: Спасибо но мне помог ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35547860/how-to-install-robomongo-from-tar-gz-file-as-a-program-in-ubuntu-15-10